# Can't open Trash: operation not supported

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop, trash

I messed up with some .h files some days ago and since then I have strange issues with my Linux Mint 17.

I cannot open my Trash, I get an error saying something like "sorry could not display all the contents of trash /// operation not supported".
If I try to open Computer, I get a similar "not supported" error.

Moreover, I can't change the theme (it ignores every time I select a theme) nor the image of some icons, folders... I also lack things that I assume that should come by defect, e.g. I cannot access to the Chat Room in the Welcome Screen.

I have done quite a lot of search of these problems, but none of the solutions worked for me. I am of course ready to share the output of any command

Comment: What desktop environment are you using? KDE/Xfce/...? WHat happens if you create a new user and log in using this account? You might consider the quick and dirty way: Backup your files, delete your account (and the home directory of it), recreate your account and try again. Be sure to **backup first**! When reinstalling the backup be sure to leave out the config files that might have caused the problems... Anyway, **backup first**!

Comment: How do I know which is my desktop environment? (I think it is Cinnamon and I am quite sure it is not Xfce)

Comment: In any case, I want to avoid the 'start-from-scratch' solution because I have some programs I need that took long to download and compile, not to mention the problems I had to get the NVIDIA card in use instead of low resolution X.

Right now, I don't have major problems and I can open the programs I need. I guess I can live with a boring desktop

Answer (score 3):

A little help, to mitigate this problem, though not a complete solution: This help will provide access to your deleted files, as long as your trash is not fully functional yet.

The Trash folder can be accessed typing following:

```
cd ~/.local/share/Trash
```

The Trash folder has three subfolders:

- `files`: here you find the **deleted files**
- `info`: here is the information about the **original directory** of each deleted file.
- `expunged`: (I do not know exactly its purpose)

Comment: thanks a lot!! love from jesus

Answer (score 0):

In my case, creating the directory `~/.local/share/Trash/expunged` and logging out and back in, it fixed the problem. I'm on Mint 20.1.